# i want to add every new json data which i get from this api but it updates the files instead of appending it what to do

Tags: python, json

I want to add every new json data which I get from this api but it  updates the files instead of appending it what to do

`Code`

```
import requests
import json

r=requests.get(url="http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json")
a=r.json()

latitude=a["iss_position"]["latitude"]
longitude=a["iss_position"]["longitude"]
timestamp=a["timestamp"]

new_data={
    "timestamp": timestamp,
    "message": "success",
    "iss_position": {
        "latitude": latitude,
        "longitude": longitude
    }
}

with open("./35/test.json",mode="r") as data_file:
    load=json.load(data_file)
    load.update(new_data)
with open("./35/test.json",mode="w") as data_file:  
    json.dump(load,data_file,indent=4)
```

`Output`

I was expecting this code will do this

```
{
    "timestamp": 1690471995,
    "message": "success",
    "iss_position": {
        "latitude": "-40.3966",
        "longitude": "172.0519"
    }

"timestamp": 1690472149,
    "message": "success",
    "iss_position": {
        "latitude": "-45.6057",
        "longitude": "-176.9845"
    }
}
```

to my test.json file but it does not append rather it just keeps on updating the old one

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a `json` file. Plus your expected output is not `json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're writing over the same `key`s; `dict`ionaries don't allow multiples of the same `key`.

One work around would be to have unique `key`s associated with each data entry, for example the `timestamp`s:

```
new_data = {
    'timestamp_ ' + str(timestamp): {
        "timestamp": timestamp,
        "message": "success",
        "iss_position": {
            "latitude": latitude,
            "longitude": longitude
        }
    }
}
```

This just requires another level of nesting; each data entry is now associated with a specific `timestamp`.